# Postgres orphaned files in base directory

Tags: postgresql

The Postgres file system is out of synch with the database. 
Basically, some tables were dropped in Postgres but the files under /base still exist.
Now I have orphaned files taking up too much space. How do I reclaim the disk space back? 
I'd rather not mess with deleting files from the PG data directory unless I am certain they can be deleted.

I tried locating the file system oid in pg_class but they don't exist.

When I calculate db sizes using SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(db)); 
The Master is 100G larger than the slave so there is definitely space that needs to be reclaimed but how?

Comment: That *really* shouldn't happen. PostgreSQL version? Filesystem? Any idea what the circumstances that surrounded the problem were?

Comment: If they're truly orphaned, you're going to have to identify and delete them. But yeah, shouldn't happen. You'd need to get a file listing, then get the relfilenode for each file that exists from pg_class and filter it out of the listing, leaving only the suspected-orphans. You'll also have to filter out visibility map, freespace map, etc files, and to handle the fact that big tables have multiple extents.

Comment: PG version is 9.1.14 running on Debian Linux. We promoted a slave server to a master. That might be the reason but I am not 100% sure. I just noticed a big discrepancy in db size and did a file system compare between the master and another slave and noticed all these orphaned files. So it sounds very complicated to clean up this mess then?